# Is there anyway to turn off Impersonation in core .net code

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there anyway to turn off Impersonation in **`.net-core 3.1`**. Could anyone please provide any sample.

Comment: AFAIK ASP.NET core does not even support impersonation implicitly. You'd have to explicitly enable it using [WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=net-6.0#System_Security_Principal_WindowsIdentity_RunImpersonated_Microsoft_Win32_SafeHandles_SafeAccessTokenHandle_System_Action_) to wrap relevant parts of your code. Do you want to disable what this function does?

Comment: we are planning to achieve below condition in core .net.       WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(System.IntPtr.Zero)

Comment: You should include the whole thing you're planning to do. I'm feeling you're asking how to revert back after using impersonation -- but nothing in your question says that.

Comment: We would want to stop impersonate in .NET core 3.1, we are trying to send a document to network printer which is installed on the developers laptop but my program is not able to find the network printer installed on my PC. I have gone thru few articles and they mentioned that the code I am trying to execute needs to run by disabling/stopping impersonate.                                                                                                                          
                                                                            viewer.PrintDocumentWithSettings(pgs, ps);

Comment: The actual 101 to get started is to learn what are the key differences of a web application and a desktop application. Your code in ASP.NET Core runs as the application pool identity on IIS and executes in system session (session 0), so naturally it won't be able to access certain resources such as network printer installed for the developer account in a user session. More in https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 So the articles you went through can be totally irrelevant and misleading.